# npm install from package.json, the dependancy -v yields command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Reinstalled node/npm from scratch and after npm install I can see the node_modules folder with all of the content from package.json. Checking gulp -v gives command not found in the command line on a mac. If I install gulp globally, gulp -v yields the version.

Is there a way of not installing all dependancies globally to use?

Comment: Gulp's command line requires the global version to work.  I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally gulp is a package which is used to run some task. These task might need to have administrator privileges. So it is better to install it globally using "npm install -g gulp" command. Here -g means "install it globally". 
npm install  installs the package locally.